# Realm-js and Node Js: application freezes

Tags: javascript, node.js, realm

I'm testing realm-js using Node JS and WebStorm. I created a little program:

```
'use strict';
 var Realm = require('realm');

 var realm = new Realm({
     schema: [{name: 'Dog', properties: {name: 'string', age: 'int'}}]
 });

 realm.write(() => {
     realm.create('Dog', {name: 'Rex', age: 3});
     realm.create('Dog', {name: 'Jack', age: 5});
 });

 var dogs = realm.objects('Dog');
 var anyDogs = dogs.filtered('age = 5');
 console.log(anyDogs);
```

During execution I received the following answer:

```
Results { '0': RealmObject { name: 'Jack', age: 5 } }
```

It seems ok, but after this application freezes and I can return to edit mode by pushing Stop button only. The same situation is occurred when I start application from console:

```
$ node app.js
```

Can anybody explain me where I made an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Realm object has an entry on the Node.js event loop in order to handle updates and change notifications and that's what keeps the Node.js app running - it's waiting in case a notification comes up, just like the net.Socket object in Node.js.

The solution would be to call `realm.close()` on the Realm file so it removes itself from the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

this is the issue in realm itself
it is still opened
https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1387

an ugly workaround so far is 
`process.exit()`